# how do i create a limit of command line entries in java

Tags: java, try-catch

My program allows you to enter a number and press enter. Then the program asked you to give it another number up till you get to 21 numbers. the point is it gives you the average of your numbers. If you wanted you can enter as many numbers on one entry and it will still work. How can I make it so you can only enter one number at a time?

Also how can I stop any entries besides numbers from being added?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

class programTwo
{   
    private static Double calculate_average( ArrayList<Double> myArr )
    {
        Double sum = 0.0;
        for (Double number: myArr)
        {
            sum += number;
        }
        return sum/myArr.size(); // added return statement
    }

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Double> myArr = new ArrayList<Double>();
        int count = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter a number to be averaged, repeat up to 20 times:");
        String inputs = scan.nextLine();

    while (!inputs.matches("[qQ]") )
    {

        if (count == 20)
        {
            System.out.println("You entered more than 20 numbers, you suck!");
            break;
        }

        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(inputs); // create a new scanner out of our single line of input
        myArr.add(scan2.nextDouble());
        count += 1;
        System.out.println("Please enter another number or press Q for your average");

        inputs = scan.nextLine();
    }
    Double average = calculate_average(myArr);
    System.out.println("Your average is: " + average);
}}
```

Comment: If user enters something that is not a number, an `InputMismatchException` will be thrown. You need to catch it.

Comment: ok so I need to add a try and a catch to the main method? How will I illustrate anything but a number? and how will this effect my inputs.matches for q and Q ?

Comment: You are already inside the condition `!inputs.matches("[qQ]")`, so this will not affect the program behavior when the user enters "q" or "Q".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user types something other than a "q" or "Q", which is also not a valid number, then an `InputMismatchException` will be thrown. You just need to catch that exception, display an appropriate message, and ask the user to continue. This can be done as follows:

```
try {
    myArr.add(scan2.nextDouble());
    count += 1;
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Very funny! Now follow the instructions, will you?");
}
```

The rest of your code need not change.

Comment: Thanks a ton this really put things in to perspective for me. I am getting an error on the line with the catch. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm ... that's strange. I actually copy-pasted your code and added the try/catch block. Can you post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: omg fixed. Sorry thanks a lot you really helped me more then you know.

Comment: ok that fixed the error but now when they program runs its stuck in a loop where we added it.

Comment: It needed a return at the end of the loop.